# React.js How can have an onClick function apply to all component divs

Tags: reactjs

I have the **handleClick** function that simply console.logs the **initIndex** state. I want it to work on the **SecondComponent** div too. At the moment, even though I have a **handleClick** function in the **SecondComponent** it does not fire the event.

Ideally I don't want to repeat the **handleClick** function again in the **SecondComponent**. What am I missing?

I am still quite new to react and it's baffling me.

```
var PlayAppComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState : function(){
        return {
          initIndex : true
        };
      },

      handleClick: function() {
        console.log("is "+ this.state.initIndex)
      },  

     render: function(){
        return (
          <div>
          <h2 className="visible" onClick={this.handleClick}>TRUE</h2>
          <SecondComponent />
          </div>
        );
      }

    });
var SecondComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState : function(){
    return {
      initIndex : true
    };
  },

  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="visible" onClick={this.handleClick}>TRUE</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

});

ReactDOM.render(
  <PlayAppComponent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks
Moe

Comment: You can pass `handleClick` through props - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/45110/

Comment: @AlexanderT. answer should fit you, although the **handleClick** method will be bound to the PlayAppComponent state. You might want to pass the appropriate state as an argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your handle function as a attribute to second component and then call that function on onclick handler like below

```
var PlayAppComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState : function(){
    return {
      initIndex : true
    };
  },

  handleClick: function() {
    console.log("is "+ this.state.initIndex)
  },  

 render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
      <h2 className="visible" onClick={this.handleClick}>TRUE</h2>
      <SecondComponent handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    )};
  }

});
var SecondComponent = React.createClass({
   getInitialState : function(){
     return {
          initIndex : true
     };
    },
   handleClick: function() {
     this.props.handleClick();
   },  
   render: function(){
     return (
        <div>
           <h2 className="visible" onClick={this.handleClick}>TRUE</h2>
        </div>
     );
    }

});

ReactDOM.render(
  <PlayAppComponent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not added handle click method in second component. Try below code.

```
var PlayAppComponent = React.createClass({
getInitialState : function(){
    return {
      initIndex : true
    };
  },

  handleClick: function() {
    console.log("is "+ this.state.initIndex)
  },  

  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
      <h2 className="visible" onClick={this.handleClick}>TRUE</h2>
      <SecondComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }

});
var SecondComponent = React.createClass({
getInitialState : function(){
return {
  initIndex : true
};
},
 handleClick: function() {
    console.log("is "+ this.state.initIndex)
 },  
 render: function(){
  return (
  <div>
    <h2 className="visible" onClick={this.handleClick}>TRUE</h2>
   </div>
   );
   }

 });

 ReactDOM.render(
 <PlayAppComponent />,
 document.getElementById('app')
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.props.handleClick in SecondComponent

delete getInitialState in SecondComponent

```
var PlayAppComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState : function(){
    return {
      initIndex : true
    };
  },

  handleClick: function() {
    console.log("is "+ this.state.initIndex)
  },  

 render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
      <h2 className="visible" onClick={this.handleClick}>TRUE</h2>
      <SecondComponent handleClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    )};
  }

});
var SecondComponent = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
     return (
        <div>
           <h2 className="visible" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>TRUE</h2>
        </div>
     );
    }

});

ReactDOM.render(
  <PlayAppComponent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```